# Prove equality of $\sigma$-algebras $\sigma(X_n; n\in \mathbb{N}) = \sigma\left( \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sigma(X_k; k < n) \right)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

I tried to prove the equality of the $\sigma$-algebras below, but I am not sure if my proof is correct.

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of measurable functions from $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ to $(E, \mathcal{E})$. Prove that:

$$ \mathcal{X}_{\infty} = \sigma\left( \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{X}_n \right) $$

where

$$ \mathcal{X}_{\infty} = \sigma(X_n; n\in \mathbb{N})  $$

$$  \mathcal{X}_n = \sigma(X_k; k < n) $$

And here is my attempt:

We have the first inclusion:

$$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \mathcal{X}_n \subset \mathcal{X}_{\infty} \implies  \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{X}_n  \subset \mathcal{X}_{\infty} \implies \sigma\left(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{X}_n\right) \subset \mathcal{X}_{\infty} $$

Now let $A \in \mathcal{X}_{\infty}$. We have:

$$ \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \; \mbox{such that} A = X_n^{-1}(B), B \in \mathcal{E}$$
$$ \implies A \in \mathcal{X}_{n+1} \implies A \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{X}_n $$

$$ \implies \mathcal{X}_{\infty} \subset \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{X}_n \subset \sigma\left( \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{X}_n \right)$$

Is it correct? Thank you for your help!

Comment: The step [let $A \in \mathcal{X}_{\infty}$. We have: $ \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \; \mbox{such that}\ A = X_n^{-1}(B), B \in \mathcal{E}$] is quite wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see! What if I take $\mathcal{A} = \{K \in \mathcal{F} | K = X_n^{-1}(B), B \in \mathcal{E}, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, so that $\mathcal{X}_{\infty} = \sigma(\mathcal{A})$. If $A \in \mathcal{A}$, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, B \in \mathcal{E}$ such that $A = X_n^{-1}(B)$. So $A \in \mathcal{X}_{n+1} \implies A \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathcal{X}_n \implies \mathcal{A} \subset \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathcal{X}_n \implies \sigma(\mathcal{A}) \subset \sigma\left(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathcal{X}_n\right) $. Does that fix the mistake?

Comment: It seems correct now. A quicker way to write it down:
$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{X_n}^{-1}(\mathcal{E}) \subseteq \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}{X_k}^{-1}(\mathcal{E}) \subseteq\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sigma\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}{X_k}^{-1}(\mathcal{E})\right) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathcal{X}_n$.
Now take $\sigma$ of both sides.